# How to convert denormalized data to normalized data and vice versa or transpose in R

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

```
Japan_n US_n Canada_n Japan_mean US_mean Canada_mean Japan_cv US_cv Canada_cv
76      55     89       145.49    163.78    122.18     23.12   25.47   13.85
```

I want my output in following format in R:

```
        n    mean     cv
Japan  76    145.99   23.12
US     55    163.78   25.47
Canada 89    122.18   13.85
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There are many 'reshape' and 'transpose' questions on the `r` tag here at Stackoverflow which would provide an answer to this query. This looks suspiciously like a course question or homework too - as such it is expected that you would typically show some independent effort first before asking for assistance.

Comment: `dplyr` has a nice function `ends_with` which you could use to subset columns and "melt" them into a long format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- structure(list(Japan_n = 76L, 
                       US_n = 55L, 
                       Canada_n = 89L, 
                       Japan_mean = 145.49, 
                       US_mean = 163.78, 
                       Canada_mean = 122.18, 
                       Japan_cv = 23.12, 
                       US_cv = 25.47, 
                       Canada_cv = 13.85), 
                  .Names = c("Japan_n", "US_n",
                             "Canada_n", "Japan_mean", 
                             "US_mean", "Canada_mean", 
                             "Japan_cv", "US_cv", "Canada_cv"), 
                  class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c(NA, -1L))

my_solution <-
    gather(data, col_01, col_02) %>% 
    separate(., col_01, into = c("geo", "stat")) %>% 
    spread(., stat, col_02)

my_solution

     geo    cv   mean  n
1 Canada 13.85 122.18 89
2  Japan 23.12 145.49 76
3     US 25.47 163.78 55
```